# Может ли юла катиться? Катится юла - применимое выражение?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Может ли юла катиться? Катится юла - применимое выражение?

Comment: Кати́ться — вращаясь, переворачиваясь, двигаться, перемещаться по какой-либо поверхности (о движении, совершаемом однократно или в определённом направлении, в отличие от сходного по смыслу гл. кататься). _Расписная Танцовщица На одной ноге кружится. А устала, накружилась — на бочок и покатилась. Вертится волчком, Катится — бочком._ (В. Стручков).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что нет. Катится предмет лишь в одном направлении, как шар для боулинга. При этом катящийся предмет делает это за счёт оборотов по поверхности. Зато юла может КАТАТЬСЯ. Разница этих слов в том, что катающийся предмет, во-первых, может попеременно двигаться в разных направлениях (как юла), во-вторых, вовсе не обязательно совершает движение за счёт собственного вращения по поверхности (как катающийся наездник).

В Вашем случае я бы заменил "катится юла" на "ездит/движется/кружит/вращается юла" и даже на "ходит юла". В художественном тексте можно пойти дальше и говорить том, что юла даже танцует (если позволяет выбранный стиль).

**Однако.** Катится юла всё-таки может, но только в том случае, когда она упала на бок и катится уже лежа, как колесо, на поверхности.